# PDF Generation Library for Java

Tags: java, pdf-generation, jasper-reports, itext, apache-fop

I know this has been asked before, but I'm still undecided on which PDF generation framework to use for my current project.

My requirements

- on-the-fly generation of PDF documents (mainly order forms, invoices)
- Java based
- easy to layout
- should be open source
- easy to change layout

A lot of people seem to use *iText*, but I have some concerns (apart from the changed licence) regarding separation of concerns: In an HTML context there's good MVC support, where I usually stick to Spring MVC and FreeMarker to separate logic and layout. I'm a little bit worried that with iText you end up mixing code and layout a lot.

I am aware, that *Apache FOP* could be a solution here, but then again I find XSLT tedious to work with and I read that FOP can be slow when it comes to huge throuput of many documents?

I also considered *JasperReports*, but from my understanding this is more suited for  reports containing tabular datasets rather than single documents such as invoices which require a lot of layout formatting?

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Pang et al.: I really like you guys :D I know the off-topic rules, but still: This is _easily_ my most popular question, with the most upvotes and the most views, so I guess asking this kind of questions _is_ useful to users on SO. Why you keep closing such questions is completely beyond my mind.

Comment: Haberi I too don't understand it. In having a question in a similar vein closed, they recommened a SO site for software recommendations instead, but I was asking for a library or framework to facilitate implementing the shunting yard algorithm (which I'm implemented quite a few times) anyways it doesn't matter if it is a Word processor, or a software library, or a software framework apparently that is the right place to ask... which is fine it is easy to ask but hardly anyone will frequent who will actually have an answer!

Comment: Looks like `iText: 4.2.0` may have been the last version that had more permissive open-source licensing.  However that version was also forked to [OpenPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF), which appears has continued the same licensing that is more permissive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Give JasperReports a try. Use [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) to create the .jrxml files. JapserReports can handle complex layouts. For those parts of the report based on different queries have a look at using subreports embedded into the main report.

Just like @Adrian Smith's solution this approach will separate the report layout editing from the data sourcing.

Comment: +1 That looks like a good product too!

Comment: Thanks Janek, I think I'll prototype using Jasper

Comment: Just in case anybody from the future is stumbling across this old thread: Use [JasperSoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) now instead of iReport.

Comment: JasperReports is a heavyweight reporting application. It does PDFs, but integrating it into another application is a complicated affair (I'm speaking from experience). I'd choose something simpler, preferably a library.

Answer (score 9):

I have implemented a good solution where my software creates a format-independent "pure" XML file, then I give my boss the XSD and he puts it into [Altova StyleVision](http://www.altova.com/stylevision.html) where he can WYSIWYG design reports based on data he plucks out from the XSD. That software produces an XSLT. So my program:

- Produces the format-independent "pure" XML
- Transforms it with the XSLT, the output of which is XML-FO
- Use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to convert the XML-FO into PDF

This is a really great solution, means no more do I (as a programmer) have to change my code each time my boss wants to change a color in the report, my job is simply to produce "pure" XML.

**Update:** I should also point out that I give my boss access to our SVN repository with Tortoise SVN which is sufficiently easy to use that he can use it without error. So he can check the XSLT files straight into SVN and run the build/deploy without even having to interrupt me from my work. Obviously that workflow only works with people who are sufficiently exact that they don't make mistakes etc., but it works out well for us in that case.

Answer (score 9):

Based on my experience, I would suggest you to consider following [Java PDF Libraries](http://www.techsagar.com/top-3-open-source-java-libraries-for-creating-and-manipulating-pdf-documents/) for creating PDF reports,

1. DynamicReports
2. Apache PDF Box
3. iText PDF
4. PDF Clown

For your requirement, I think [DynamicReports](https://github.com/dynamicreports/dynamicreports) would be the right choice. I have been using Dynamic Reports from last 3 years for all my PDF Reporting requirements. With a very less amount of code, you can easily create a truly dynamic PDF. Dynamicreports is a wrapper around Jasper Report. So, it internally makes use of Jasper report.

Comment: It looks like the link to DynamicReports is dead

Comment: I have updated the link. The original website on which Dynamic Reports was hosted is no longer available. The link is down from the last couple of months. Now, few members from the community are maintaining this project.

Answer (score 2):

[Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) allows you to create templates in Word or OpenOffice writer - separating concerns nicely and layout is then in the most familiar tools.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) for a while and I really like it.

What we do is use [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) to generate dynamic OpenOffice.org documents (which internally uses FreeMarker). Then we convert these documents to PDF documents using JODConverter.

It sounds like a lot of work, but it really isn't.

Comment: Just wondering Shervin, is this still the system you use and would recommend?  Or have you found something better since 2010?

Comment: @the_new_mr I wouldn't recommend this now. There are better alternatives out there

Comment: Would you mind letting me know what these are please? :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is

- to create your documents in PostScript format and then
- convert it to pdf using ghostscript (ps2pdf)