# java pdf print NetBeans

Tags: java, pdf, printing, netbeans-7

Hi everyone this is my first question at the site .

i use  : NetBeans IDE 7.0.1  and i want to print a PDF with java , but i dont know where is the mistake in my code ,  please help me .

there is a good code which one print a GIF  used  the 5-th printer.

---

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
pras.add(new Copies(1));
PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);


if (pss.length == 0)  throw new    RuntimeException("No printer services available.");
    PrintService ps = pss[5];
System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);
DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("a.gif");
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);

job.print(doc, pras);
fin.close();
```

---

But i dont know whats wrong the following code which try to print a PDF at the same printer(5th)

---

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
pras.add(new Copies(1));
PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF, pras);


if (pss.length == 0)  throw new    RuntimeException("No printer services available.");
    PrintService ps = pss[5];
System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);
DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test.PDF");
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF, null);

job.print(doc, pras);
fin.close();
```

---

this is  the program answer : " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No printer services available.  "

If you have any idea please write it 
Thanks

Comment: It seems to be saying that you don't have a default printer on your system to print in PDF. Have you had a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355025/create-pdf-with-java

Comment: unfortunately , i have  a default printer ,so  the problem is not that

Comment: Does your default printer support a PDF stream as direct input? because it seems to me that this is what you are trying to do...

Comment: Thanks all  answers the solution is that my printer cant print PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generally print a PDF directly from Java. Iwrote a blog article about ways to do it at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/

Comment: true--->   ( I  "can't generally print a PDF directly from Java" )