# free pdf creation on GAE for business purposes (not itext or pdfjet)

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf-generation

GAE allows to create at most 100 pdf files a day. I need more. Yes, you can request more but you have to contact Google, request for an app then later request for another. it is unpractical.

i would like to convert html to pdf OR create PDF from scratch on GAE. But itext and pdfjet are not free if you use them for business. Do you know any framework that runs on GAE that is free and supports utf8 when I use it on GAE for business purposes. Preferably for java.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ It converts plain XHTML+CSS to PDF. I've been using it to create documents on a large scale. BTW, Openoffice can export styled documents as neat, readable XHTML which served me as a good starting point in creating the intermediary XHTML document.

Comment: That page says "render to PDF (via iText)", so it uses iText, which is pricey in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can [request a quota increase](http://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?contact_type=AppEngineQuotaRequest).

Or look at other options to create PDF in Java: [Create PDF with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355025/create-pdf-with-java)