# How to save file as pdf

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, pdf

I have a website that's not ready for production yet. When the user purchase the product it is generating the receipt. What i need to do is i want to give the option to the user to save as pdf. On click of that icon receipt has to be downloaded. I have no idea to do this.

Here is the sample receipt:
[image]

`On Click of this "save as PDF" i need to download this receipt.`

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: I recommend you http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: Jasper Reports can do it.

Comment: try this:(http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355025/create-pdf-with-java

Answer (score 3):

Your problems can be broken down into following pieces.

When the user clicks "Save as PDF"

- Generate PDF:

  **iText** comes very handy in doing this (its free & open source). [Here is an example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=76) of generating a tabular data in PDF. There are tons of example from iText
- Download the PDF.

  Once the PDF is generated, the same can be send to the user via `response` object like any file. [Here is an example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/servlet-code-to-download-text-file-from-website-java/) of downloading a text file. The same can be used for downloading any file.

Hope this helps.