# Database table data to pdf file using java

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I have to create a PDF files using datas from database. I found some similar questions like this in this site. Most of the answer suggest use of iText. But i have to do it using java code only without using iText and all. Is there anyway I can do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for apache fop

Comment: Just to clarify: iText is available for multiple languages, including Java. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355025/create-pdf-with-java) has plenty of suggestions apart from iText.

Comment: why without using third party API?

Comment: @java Man..yes. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

so you planning for iTEXT2 ?
you can do it same with many other utility for same but tricky hard way

Comment: The problem is that i cant use iText. Is there any other way apart from iText ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) to interact with the database and create objects that represent your data - after that you can use any API to create a PDF file/report: check [Apache PDFBox](http://Apache%20PDFBox) or [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)