# Simplest way to fill out a PDF file in Java. ( creating invoices )

Tags: java, export-to-pdf

I am trying to find a good method for creating customer invoices in Java.  I have been looking into Jasper Reports but it seems a bit heavy for what I need and I am working through some troubles with it now.

I am just looking for a simple way to edit fields and tables in a pdf file.  Alternatively, a way to create a PDF in java with a logo and a table of different charges for a particular customer.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF Generation Library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986105/pdf-generation-library-for-java)

Comment: Essentially you are asking for a software recommendation. This is off topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Alternatively, a way to create a PDF in java with a logo and a table of different charges for a particular customer." - Use itext. It is a stable and time tested library.

There is another library - flying saucer which uses itext internally but works really well with xml, html or xhtml. This meets almost all needs and takes good care of styles and formatting. You can even export an html document to pdf.
https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer